# Delete local data from all subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, cross-domain, local-storage, subdomain

Is it possible to remove all local data including `sessions`, `cookies`, `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` of all `*.domain.com` from a Rails app at `rails.domain.com`?

I want like to clear users' session for all of `*.domain.com` when they logout from one of my app so they need to login again just like Google does it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by sending the following HTTP header in the response after looging out:  **Clear-Site-Data: ***

please check https://w3c.github.io/webappsec/specs/clear-site-data/published/2015-07-FPWD.html#clear_site_data for more details.

Comment: Can you give an example? Sending `Clear-Site-Data: *; includeSubdomains` doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the right syntax (tested against Chrome v.67.0.3396.79)

```
Clear-Site-Data: "cache", "cookies", "storage"
```

So in Rails that would be something like:

```
response.headers['Clear-Site-Data'] = '"cache", "cookies", "storage"'
```

Couldn't get the `*` wildcard, nor the `executionContexts`, nor the `includeSubdomains` bit to work though but it seems to be doing the job.
Figured out thanks to this :
https://github.com/yzyz/chromium/commit/cc19a8388814caf28b15e348a2e1941b6b66e370